# Type 'K' cannot be used to index type '{ [key in keyof K]: V; }'.ts(2536)

Tags: typescript

I want to make a method that returns a new object from my custom Object type.

```
/*
    type K represent the type of key in an object 
    type V represent the type of value in an object
*/
class Group<K,V> extends Map<K,V> {
   toObject() {
    const result: { [key in keyof K]: V } = {} as { [key in keyof K]: V }
    for (const [key, value] of this.entries()) {
      result[key] = value //Error:Type 'K' cannot be used to index type '{ [key in keyof K]: V; }'.ts(2536) 
    }
    return result
  }
}
```

key and value have types K and V respectively.

I don't clearly understand the error message it would be good if you explain it to me.

I also tried to make it easier.

```
class Group<K, V> extends Map<K, V> {
  toObject() {
    const result = {}
    for (const [key, value] of this.entries()) {
      result[key] = value //Error:Type 'K' cannot be used to index type '{}'.ts(2536) 
    }
    return result
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a [mre] because I don't know what `K` or `this` is.  But my *guess* is that `K` is a keylike type and that `keyof K` is therefore not what you want (if `K` is already a keylike type, then `keyof K` is going to a key of the key, which is like, `"toUpperCase"` or something).  Also note that in `{[key in keyof K]: V}`, you shouldn't use a name like `key`; it's a *type parameter*, not a key name.  It should be, for example, `{[P in keyof K]: V}` (or more likely `{[P in K]: V}` or even more colloquially `Record<K, V>`)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wOJZyW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz sorry I'm new to this. I edited it to follow a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKV5gm) meet your needs?  It's only possible to use a value of type `K` as a key if it is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a key-like type, such as `PropertyKey` (an alias for `string | number | symbol`).  If that works for you I can write up an answer; if not, let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @jcalz Yes and no, It fixed the problem but it create a new problem.
It seems that typescript makes keys to be constant.

Comment: @jcalz Playground link is too long to write in the comment so I put it in a question post at the bottom.

Comment: @jcalz I'm sorry.

Comment: There's a difference between it "creating a new problem" and allowing you to proceed until you run into a separate problem you already had. You were locked out of your car and so I gave you the car keys, and now you have discovered that the fuel tank is empty. Giving you the car keys did not empty the tank. Please limit Stack Overflow posts to a single question, and post followup questions separately (after searching for existing answers).

Comment: It's okay.  So, if you agree that the above change fixes the particular issue where `Type 'K' cannot be used to index type '{ [key in keyof K] : ...}` happens, I can write up an answer to explain it.  (The followup question looks like it will have to do with inference; you can always write `new Group<string, number>([['a1', 1], ['b2', 2]]);` to fix that one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is that you were using `keyof K` instead of just `K`. [The `keyof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) gives you the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the keys (often [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types)s like `"a"`) of the type it applies to.  `keyof {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}` is `"a" | "b" | "c"`.  So `keyof K` would be whatever keys you'd expect a value of type `K` to have.  If `K` is something like `string`, then `keyof K` is something like `keyof string` which is:

```
type KeyofString = keyof string;
/* type KeyofString = number | typeof Symbol.iterator | "toString" | "charAt" | 
    "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" |
    "match" | "replace" | "search" | "slice" | "split" | "substring" | 
    "toLowerCase" | "toLocaleLowerCase" | "toUpperCase" | "toLocaleUpperCase" | 
    "trim" | "length" | "substr" | "valueOf" | "codePointAt" | "includes" | 
    "endsWith" | "normalize" | "repeat" | "startsWith" | "anchor" | "big" | 
    "blink" | "bold" | "fixed" | "fontcolor" | "fontsize" | "italics" | 
    "link" | "small" | "strike" | "sub" | "sup" | "padStart" | "padEnd" */
```

Unless you want `result` to have keys like `"toUpperCase"` or `"trim"`, then `keyof K` is not right.

If `result[key]` makes sense, and if `key` is of type `K`, then you want a type you can index into with keys of type `K`.  If you put a value `value` of type `V` into that property, then you want a type whose values are of type `V`. The [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) `{[P in K]: V}` is just such a type; the keys are `K` and the values are `V`. This sort of mapped type where the value types don't depend on the specific keys is often called a "record" and is used often enough that there's a [`Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) provided for this purpose.

Let's use `Record<K, V>` then:

```
class Group<K, V> extends Map<K, V> {
  toObject() {
    const result = {} as Record<K, V>; // error!
    // -----------------------> ~
    // Type 'K' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'
    for (const [key, value] of this.entries()) {
      result[key] = value // okay
    }
  }
}
```

So, that resolves the `result[key] = value` error, but it introduces a new error.  The type `Record<K, V>` is an error in `K`, where `K` does not satisfy a constraint of being a keylike type, `string | number | symbol`.  Note that `string | number | symbol` is used often enough that there is also a `PropertyKey` utility type provided to be a short alias for this.

And that really is a problem if your `Group<K, V>` can really have an *arbitrary* type for `K`.  A [`Map` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in JavaScript can hold "keys" of any type whatsoever, while a plain object like `result` can only hold keys of a `PropertyKey` type.  For example, you can use `Date` objects as "keys" to a `Map` but not as keys to a plain JavaScript object:

```
const date = new Date();
const m = new Map<Date, string>();
m.set(date, "hello"); // okay
const o: any = {};
o[date] = "hello"; // error
```

So if your `Group<K, V>` really needs a value of type `Record<K, V>`, then that means you have to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `K` so that the compiler will only let `new Group<K, V>` exist when `K` is sufficiently keylike:

```
class Group<K extends PropertyKey, V> extends Map<K, V> {
  toObject() {
    const result = {} as Record<K, V>; // okay
    for (const [key, value] of this.entries()) {
      result[key] = value // okay
    }
  }
}
```

Now everything compiles as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIHsBmBlYAnAlgOwOZQF4oBreZKAZwx1wG4AoAegCopRJYzVq9CpsArgFsARhHRQAPm3ARyKEKIQAbAHSZg4gIbAEE6QCJdaLHgNSoBgMYALLegCCwc9PpR3l2-YDCCACYQTi6eCNhWOsEGOAEAHgDySJHKWlQAktixCUkI4coQvkJg9hAubh4GQjq2kegQYMlWJRYGFBD21c0UypiNkRT1Gn0CIlSmuMFl7kYIADIIAO7i3ilNhrpzuRBzi+jLrZG6AKpgkLsrB7M5WnnHp3urUJOW1EJJEHjANkMjGJEAbtcBBAss0rP4IAAFBA4YBBZo4KzKAQBCgTDyWd5+CgAdQ0X2a2D0lW6AC8HgZapAIp1gPZgDi8ZEtGEbHpIiJMOMLE8DCJuthiOyVH5IkhMDEICLmkhQsAwco2dLZRRMGTIhprj1Udz0QZ+YLOsTlH1qKRvkMwJEin40HSrVo-ABRDLmZiMej0MHYKhQPw6aBEbAQeZQAAi-oAFABKBhen1CPhBkMAWS0YAAPOHNAAaSg8XAAPmjDCEqlawAjfpzlhsEGUCoMMagjEYUAQxC0IE9oR9CAAXFBmSA+ABvAC+DAQAG0qxAALp8Ay1+sIAy0Zut8ToPQelhPdjQGBQSm1VrYYBsWsyDjkUjDnCD7BtkQAKwgVgv+9kUAAase6qe7wXp80AHm2SBQACSLQA+zLPm+H70G6nrJBQFBQAA4tuAgZkeEAxJoGToRC26nKAcAgLmP4FlA+GEViUCprhVE0SOZS6HEr7vhWUZQGx6Jxhep4CMoF5EOOg7oQASu+eh+OmMAsQwTwyhIEaCVAU53rmUFAgu5CfJgFCqEBWAQBQ0a8fx6L-hQInAFp8ALkQunQC2bYdl26Jjk8tTAAI6BPsJollD5Pn0EAA)